# What "domain" should I specify in JNDI login to an Active Directory Server?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi, principal

I'm wondering what "principal" I should specify to login in to an Active Directory server. Should the principal be a user inside the AD I try to log into? Or it can be a user in the domain I specify as long as the user has privileges to access the AD?

I tried both with credentials error 49. But I can log in to the AD with ldp.exe by using the Administrator account of the server that AD is installed on.

Here is my code. Many thanks for any prompt help.

```
Hashtable env= new Hashtable(11);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple"); // Also tried none w/ the same error

// What principal should I use??
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"CN=Ross,OU=Eng,DC=RossInc");//User
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain); // Tried w/ the same error

env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ross");//Password
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://myserver:389/DC=RossInc");

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); <-- Fails with AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [following example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/src/UseDiff.java) from Oracle site, the security Principal is a distinguished name.

Here is some code working for me from a computer inside the domain :

```
Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://societe.fr:389");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=administrateur,cn=users,dc=societe,dc=fr");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test.2011");
ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
```

The principal can be a user inside the AD as long as he has privileges to access the AD.

Comment: I set up the "principal" in AD and in the code. Then I used it to log in, still got the same error!

Comment: The example is valid for ther directory services only.

Answer (score 0):

You either can provide:

- NT-style login name
- Kerberos UPN (implicit UPN)
- explicit UPN (if additional UPN suffices have been defined)

More over, NEVER ever perform a simple bind! Either Digest or GSS-API.

Comment: Once again please in proper English.